# How can I validate options with args4j?

Tags: java, bean-validation, args4j

With following code,

```java
@Option(name = "age") // min = "1"
private int age;
```

How can I validate `age` field? Say must be bigger than zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place `Option` annotation on the method of the form `void methodName(T value)`.
So you can easily do it in the following way.

```
private int age;

@Option(name = "age")
void setAge(int age) {
    if (age < 1) {
        throw new CmdLineException("message");
    }
    this.age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved for myself with `bean-validation`.

Once I annotated those `@Option`s like this,

```java
class Opts {

    @Option(name = "-buffer-capacity",
            usage = "each buffer's capacity in bytes")
    @Min(1024)
    private int bufferCapacity = 65536;

    @Option(name = "-buffer-count", required = true,
            usage = "number of buffers to allocate")
    @Min(1)
    @Max(1024)
    private int bufferCount;
}
```

I can validate it using `bean-validation`.

```java
final Opts opts;
final ValidatorFactory factory
    = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
final Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
final Set<ConstraintViolation<Opts>> violations
    = validator.validate(opts);
```